# socket.makefile() not sending data

Tags: python, sockets

I have a server that should send text to the client with `socket.makefile()` but it doesn't receive anything from `.write()` ("ABC") even though that function returns the correct number of characters (3). Why not?

The client successfully receives text sent through `socket.send()` ("DE" repeated) so I think the client is OK.

Here is the server code after creating a listening socket s:

```
connection, addr = s.accept()
socket_file = connection.makefile('w')
while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    number = socket_file.write("ABC") # Not received by client. Why?
    print(number) # Shows 3 as expected
    connection.send("DE".encode()) # Received by client
```

Comment: I'm guessing that the file object buffers data, whereas the connection object goes directly to the socket.  Consider calling `flush()` on the file object after the `write` call.   But more likely, probably not a good idea to mix the two modes together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It needs

```
socket_file.flush()
```

after `.write()` to flush the buffer and send it immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Turn off buffering by using `buffering=0`. That requires binary mode (`'wb'`). which requires sending the text as bytes (`.encode()`).

```
connection, addr = s.accept()
socket_file = connection.makefile('wb', buffering=0)
while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    number = socket_file.write("ABC".encode())
    print(number)
    connection.send("DE".encode())
```